# Combine 2 results in one in SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Update** merge

```
Cama::PostType.first.posts.joins(:custom_field_values)
.where("cama_custom_fields_relationships.custom_field_slug = ? AND 
cama_custom_fields_relationships.value LIKE ?","localization", 
"%Paris%").merge(Cama::PostType.first.posts.joins(:custom_field_values)
.where("cama_custom_fields_relationships.custom_field_slug = ? AND 
cama_custom_fields_relationships.value = ?","type-localization", "2"))
```

This also doesnt work. When executed seperatelty, it returns same AssociationRelation. I guess it only works for ActiveRecord:Relation

**Update**
I think Im looking for INTERSECT but don't know how to use it with where

There is another topic that I created and still can't find answer how to optimize it.

It goes likes this

I need to find "posts" by "other_model" values.  Other model has relationship with posts throught another table but lets keep it simple. When i do

```
Foo.joins(:other_model).where("other_model.value = ? AND other_model.value = ?", "one", "two")
```

This of course won't find me any result because it contradicts itself.

When I do with OR instead of AND

```
Foo.joins(:other_model).where("other_model.value = ? OR other_model.value = ?", "one", "two")
```

It finds posts for me but... either it has one value or either has second value and...

**I want to find posts based on other_model.value = one and other_model.value = two**

Which means it looks for 2 seperate results and then I need to just return ids that covers each other... Does it make sense ?

Comment: postgresql != mysql. Also, that looks more like some sort of wrapper library than a raw query; it's usually helpful such information in the tags.

Comment: topic speaks for itself. I want to gain some attention. I know mysql != postgresql. Some kind of queries are possible in mysql and not possible in postgresql, I added both as Im looking for any answer, concept how to solve it.

Comment: MySQL <> Postgres!!!  This doesn't look like either of the two.

Comment: Oh thats right. Im looking for concept, its ruby

Comment: Do you want do find foos that have other_model with value "one" AND another other_model with value "two"? In raw sql you can achieve this by joining other_models twice. Off the top of my head, can't tell how to do this in activerecord

Comment: omg, downvoting. People You think you are smart and orginized, Thats why stackoverflow will never change because its about who is right, not problem solving. Thanks Sergio for hint

Comment: in ruby there is merge function but it doesn't work for me. Yes you have understood me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a query like:

```
Foo
  .joins(:other_model)
  .where('other_model.value = ? OR other_model.value = ?', 'one', 'two') 
  .group('foos.id')
  .having('COUNT(other_models.id) >= 2')
```

Comment: See [`HAVING`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_(SQL)). It does basically the same as `WHERE` but runs after an aggregate function like `GROUP BY`.

Comment: why count more or equal 2 ? I will check it right now. Thank you for answer

Comment: Because you want to find all `foos` that have at least two `other_models` (the one that has `value == 'one'` and the one that has `value == 'two'`.

Comment: thank you, its seems it worked ! but I need to test it to figure it out if it really works